# Cannot return HTTP Unauthorized from delegating Handler Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement authentication in a DelegatingHandler. Here is an example below.

```
public class AuthHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var auth = request.Headers.Authorization;
        if (!auth.Scheme.Equals("UberSecureScheme"))
        {
            return new Task<HttpResponseMessage>(() => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("You have no token")
                });
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    } 
}
```

This never ever executes the task and no response is ever returned. If I change the code to do some task continuation thing like I have seen some examples then the Controller is executed first.

```
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
           .ContinueWith(task =>
           {
               var response = task.Result;
               response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
               return response;
           });
```

This is obviously a disaster. I can't let someone do a delete and then tell them that they were unauthorized to do so.

I have also come across someone saying just throw an HTTPResponseException. No matter what status code I put in there (404, 401, whatever) the browser always gets a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (!auth.Scheme.Equals("UberSecureScheme"))
{
    var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    response.ReasonPhrase = "You have no token";
    return Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response);
}
```

Comment: You are kidding me. That sorted it out. Can you please tell me why/how this works but nothing else did?

Comment: `request.CreateResponse` saves information about request, when `new HttpResponseMessage` does not. As for `ContinueWith` it call base method, so controller is executed.

Comment: I understand why the `ContinueWith` is wrong. I can't believe people have put examples of doing auth like that because it is clear from code and one simple test that it still executes the controller. But I am not 100% sure about `new HttpResponseMessage`. If I had manually copied over more information from the request would it have worked?

Comment: May be, haven't tried. You can look at source code for `request.CreateResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Async/wait.
I typed it, not copy/paste - don't ask, so hopefully no typing mistakes.... :)

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage>              SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
if (HttpContext.Current.User == null) {
    HttpResponseMessage errorResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
    errorResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Some auth related message");
    errorResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    return errorResponse;
}
return response;
```